# How to add a gui to my python project using kivy?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I want to create a gui for an old python project using kivy and I want to keep things separated between the old project classes and kivy widgets, but I don't know how to display information from a class attribute without changing it to a Kivy Property.

```
class Person(object):
    """ Person information """
    def __init__(self, name, last_name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.age = age
```

As I read how Kivy works, I think I should do something like this:

```
class PersonWidget(Widget):
    """ Person Kivy's widget """
    name = StringProperty("")
    last_name = StringProperty("")
    age = NumericProperty("")
```

And then the .kv file:

```
#:kivy 1.0.9

<PersonWidget>:

    canvas:
        pos: 0, 0
        size: 100, 100

    Label:
        text: str(root.name)
```

Ignoring the incomplete .kv file, is there any other way to print in a widget some class attributes without defining them like a Kivy Property? Because I'd like to use Person and PersonWidget to separate logic and gui code.

PD: I'm new at stackoverflow, sorry if something is confusing or wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must learn more about kivy's rules... ;o)
For your `Person` class you have to create a kv `<Person>` rule

```
<Person>:
    canvas:
        pos: 0, 0
        size: 100, 100
    Label:
        id: person_label
        text: ""
```

Inside that rule you can add any widgets, but if you want to access any of them from the `.py` side, it should have an `id` to identify it.
To use it from your class, you just have to do `self.ids.person_label.text = "The Person's name"`